# Copying a file from ROOT to home directory

Tags: root, file-copy

I am trying to copy a file from Root directory over to my home directory. I had to execute the extraction of a file as ROOT user. I can see it is extracted into root directory but I now want to access this in my home directory. I have tried a number of commands to do this but it seems to fail.

Comment: welcome to U&L, what do you mean by "extracting" ? `tar` ?  `unzip` ? a system command that must be run as root and  is redirected in a file ? can you edit your question to add more details ?

Comment: So…the extract command doesn't let you choose a directory to put your extracted files? What commands have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your username is *deirdre*:

As root, you have to move the file from root's homedir to *deirdre*'s homedir and give it ownership to *deirdre*:

```
mv /root/somefile ~deirdre/
chown deirdre ~deirdre/somefile
```

Once you've done this, you will be able to login as *deirdre* and access the file.

It isn't clear from your question whether the file is in root's home directory or in the filesystem root; if it is the last case, the commands are instead:

```
mv /somefile ~deirdre/
chown deirdre ~deirdre/somefile
```

Comment: thank you so much this worked for me finally!

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be this

> sudo cat /root/somefile | cat > ~/somefile

Explain:

- Through a pipe (i.e. `|`), the permission access right is separated

  - That means , the permision boundary can be setup like so:
  - **`sudo right command`** `|` **`normal right command`**
- What we can do then, is to `cat` out the file using sudo right, then receive the file back using `cat` and send it back to home directory